# Moving azure resources from one resource group to another

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I have two resource groups in our azure account, one(A) is having all the database(SQL) resources and other one(B) having other resources like app service, key vault, service bus etc.

Now we have decided to make a single resource group and we are trying to move SQL resources from resource group A resource group B. but it gives duplicate resources error as saying the resources we are trying to move is already there.  But I have checked properly and those resources are not in resource group B.I have checked hidden types as well.

(A)[image]

(B)
[image]

Comment: How did you move?

Comment: By clicking Move button on the top of the resource page

Comment: Did you click the Move button on the top of the `resource group`? It works on my side, did you select the options like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9bII.png?

Comment: Yes I have been selecting them. I have been trying to move this for last 2 days and it didn't work. But right now I tried and it worked. I am happy that it moved, but same time I am worried as it is not clear why didn't it move for last two days. Any insights?

Comment: I don't think it has a reason not to work unless there is a problem with the portal.

Comment: The reason happens to be because azure is more wobble. few of my colleagues has had same experience and it has automatically resolved after retrying few times.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But that was not the answer to the question as we have tried this for two days in the same way, yet didn't work. And I have explained in my previous comments I clicked the move button on the top of resource page since the beginning(Also check boxes are clicked by default). I guess I can just leave this one open for more insights from other people. Thanks